# Python re.sub grab a single character from a group

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've come across a scenario where I want to sub the string with a single character from a group.

Example. My regex is

```
^(\d{1,})\s?(ABC|DEF|GHI)
```

I want to get the digits and only the first letter of the first group (i.e. 123 A).

The following will grab the entire second group - Is it possible to grab the first character of \2 instead?

```
re.sub(regex_pattern, r'\1 \2', str)
```

Current output: 123 ABC

Desired output: 123 A

Comment: What is your string?

Comment: For example "123 ABC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function as the replacement to `re.sub`. The function will be called with a `match` object as its argument, which you can use to build the replacement string. For your situation, I'd try something like this:

```
re.sub(regex_pattern, lambda m: "{} {}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2)[0]), text)
```

Note that I've renamed your `str` variable to `text`, as it's a bad idea to use `str` as a variable name since it's also a builtin type.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this `^(\d{1,})\s?(A(?=BC)|D(?=EF)|G(?=HI))..`

This truncates the remaining 2 characters.

so, `re.sub(regex_pattern, r'\1 \2', str)` will convert

`123 ABC` *to* `123 A`

---

***update info***

If you use the new Python ***regex*** module, you'd have access to branch reset construct.

Then it's as simple as putting a capture group (2) around the first letters
(or any particular letter, in any particular item *see **note 1***) of all in the alternation ist.

This avoids the callback, thus increasing performance, and it enables you
to add intense constructs within the branch reset list.

`^(\d{1,})\s?(?|(A)BC|(D)EF|(G)HI)`

https://regex101.com/r/S9XBpb/1

Readable version

```
 ^ 
 ( \d{1,} )                    # (1)
 \s? 
 (?|                           # Branch reset 
      ( A )                         # (2)
      BC
   |  
      ( D )                         # (2)
      EF
   |  
      ( G )                         # (2)
      HI 
 )
```

*note 1*:
https://regex101.com/r/S9XBpb/2
https://regex101.com/r/S9XBpb/3 *<- Couldn't do this with a callback*

Comment: I like the approach and definitely answers the question I proposed but does not let me manipulate more items. (i.e. If I extend the expression to add more groups - this doesn't seem to work. I may be doing it wrong though)

Comment: Well, if you think you need a callback, then have at it. But, I assure you there are other ways no matter how junked up your data is.

Comment: Example `re.sub( r'^(\d{1,})\s?(A(?=(hello))|D(?=(wierdly))|G(?=(shizaaaaaaaaaaam)))\3?\4?\5?', r'\1 \2', '123 Dwierdly' ) ` results in `123 D` This gives a big performance edge over callbacks.

Comment: An another solution: re.sub(r"^(\d+)\s?(?=ABC|DEF|GHI)(\w)..",r"\1 \2",text)

Comment: @kanta - Yeah, that would be the factored out, intelligent way to do it.

Comment: even better: re.sub(r"^(\d+)\s?(?=ABC|DEF|GHI)(.)..",r"\1 \2",text)